# Codeigniter form validate for optional fileds

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have form fields email and phone.Out of these any one need to be filled.

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone[]', 'Phone', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email[]', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call a callbabk function

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('phone[]', 'Phone', 'trim|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email[]', 'Email', 'trim|xss_clean|callback_check_validation');// call a calback
```

In your callback you have to check empty fields for email and phone.

```
 function check_validation() {
       $phone=$this->input->post('phone');
       $email=$this->input->post('email');
       if(empty($phone) && empty($email)){// check empty of both filed
        $this->form_validation->set_message("check_validation", 'Atleast phone or email required');
        return FALSE;
       }else {
        return TRUE;
      }
    }
```

Comment: is need to call callback_check_validation with both set rule. or need to remove required from both.

Comment: yaa you need to remove required. You need to check it in only in one filed!